# "Lock held by this virtual machine" exception with Solr 6.6.1

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing, index

For a customer i created a solution based on CMS Sitecore 8.2.7. 
The architecture is hosted on MS Azure infrastructure and basically consists of a Content Management VM (Windows Server 2016), two Content Delivery VMs (Windows Server 2016) with a load balancer configured with a Sticky session, a SQL Server VM and three MongoDB VMs.
The caching system used is Azure Redis Cache.
The indexing system used is Solr (version 6.6.1) installed on a Windows VM (Windows Server 2016)
To connect to Solr, Sitecore uses SorlNet client version 0.4.0.2.

The problem that often occurs is that the web and analytics indexes are locked in some way on server side.
Below is an excerpt from solrJetty logs and from apache Solr server logs to show what happens on web index:

```
2020-05-01 12:59:24.631 INFO  (qtp1330278544-20) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not consume full client request
java.io.IOException: Committed before 100 Continues
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.continue100(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:210)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getInputStream(Request.java:830)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.consumeInputFully(SolrDispatchFilter.java:387)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:378)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

....

2020-05-01 13:03:04.348 INFO  (qtp1330278544-20) [   ] o.a.s.c.S.Request [sitecore_master_index]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={version=2.2} status=500 QTime=1
2020-05-01 13:03:04.348 ERROR (qtp1330278544-20) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.<init>(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:322)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.<init>(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:284)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory.getInstance(DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory.getInstance(DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:31)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorChain.createProcessor(UpdateRequestProcessorChain.java:216)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
...


2020-05-01 13:03:29.399 ERROR (qtp1330278544-60) [   x:sitecore_web_index] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [sitecore_web_index]
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:938)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1347)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:268)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:483)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:977)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:830)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:922)
... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2069)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2189)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:1071)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:949)
... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine: E:\Bitnami\solr-6.6.1-0\apache-solr\server\solr\cores_data\sitecore_web_index\index\write.lock
at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.obtainLock(FilterDirectory.java:104)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:800)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:118)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:93)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:257)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:131)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2030)
... 37 more

2020-05-01 13:03:30.821 ERROR (Finalizer) [   ] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexWriter SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!
2020-05-01 13:03:30.821 ERROR (Finalizer) [   ] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexWriter Error closing IndexWriter
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3414)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3376)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.shutdown(IndexWriter.java:1126)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1171)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:278)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.finalize(SolrIndexWriter.java:334)
at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that the web index is locked by some process, and Solr can no longer access it in writing ... is there any explanation about it? 
    From my point of view it seems like a server-side problem: I don't think it depends on Sitecore. Do you agree?
    I tried to write on Solr's commuity but got no answers. Thx!

Comment: I think your `sitecore_web_index` core is corrupted, you can try by removing old core and creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Solr source](https://gitlab.cecs.anu.edu.au/tsujamin/lucene-solr/blob/7bf019a9c2779368133850f141174febede6ad96/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrDispatchFilter.java) it looks like the connection to Solr is closing before Solr can read the query fully.

This might happen if you have particularly large queries as there are some limits that apply to the size of request headers in a lot of circumstances.  Solr also generally imposes a 1024 clause limit on queries, but this is tunable.

Set your Search log on Sitecore into DEBUG mode and check for any particularly large queries being sent to Solr.

Also, if you have out-of-process Session State with Solr you don't need sticky sessions on your load balancer.

Also++, Solr runs much better on Ubuntu than on Windows.